# SharePoint Site workflow: wait for newly created item update

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm having a site workflow and I'm creating new list item with status column value as "Pending" in one step and in the next step I want to wait for the same newly created item to update its status column value as "Approve/ Reject".
I want to use site workflow only so is there any way to wait until the current item update (item created in previous step.)

Answer (score 0):

Items created by a workflow do not trigger a second workflow by design to prevent runaway recursion.

The item created by the site workflow could be assigned a workflow with a modify trigger to allow it to run as soon as it is edited by a user. This list workflow can validate the changes made to the item and take action on valid or invalid data.